# Trim leading zeros in comma separated values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, replace, trim

Ex.Table Store

```
store_id             Employee_id
0020,0345,0002345    0234
0034                 0943
```

I tried `REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(store_id,'0',' ')),' ','0')` but it trims leading zeros for the first value alone.
How to get all storeIds of an employee without leading zeros in a sql query?

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure - have you figured out how to split the comma-separated values first?

Comment: What database are you using?  And why are you storing ids in a comma-delimited string rather than using a junction table?

Comment: mysql and yes I am storing ids in comma-delimited string.

Comment: @stanley.No .I would like to get storeids of an employee but leading zeros have to be trimmed.

Comment: `REPLACE(store_id, '0', ' ')` will remove ALL zeroes, not just leading ones.

Comment: Do you HAVE to do it in SQL? Can't you do it in the client application language, after splitting the value on commas?

Comment: FIrst thing is to stop storing ids ina  comma delimeted list. This is a SQl antipattern. You can't ever effectively query when you store things this way.

Comment: Once the leading zeros are removed - what do you want to do next? Actually, you might not need to worry about these leading zeros, but benefit from implicit conversion as in `SELECT '00045' + 0, '00045' + 0 < 44, '00045' + 0 < 46;`. Or you could convert explicitely `SELECT CONVERT('00045', SIGNED INTEGER), CONVERT('-00045', SIGNED INTEGER);` with the leading zeros still in place. (Yes, you'd still need to split the comma separated values…)

Comment: What forces you to keep the "store_id" as comma separated values? Is your "Employee_id" of some character type as well - or `ZEROFILL`ed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove the leading zeros -- and there aren't too many -- you can use `replace()`:

```
select substr(replace(replace(replace(concat(',', store_id), ',0', ','),
                              ',0', ','),
                       ',0', ',')
              2, length(store_id)
```

This just replaces a comma followed by a zero with a comma, adding and removing a comma at the beginning and end of the string.  Different databases have slightly different names for `substr()` and `length()`, but the functionality is generally there.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a table in an rdbms, it violates 1NF. You should avoid doing this. If you possible use junction tables or reference tables. Else you could use the same schema and insert multiple entries corresponding to a single Employee_id.

Now, To solve this in a generic manner, there is only one solution, **UDF's**. **User defined function** specification is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html)

or move this kind of processing to the client.